# Derived Objects stored in one common container. How to avoid casting

Tags: c++

Hey dear folks i'm doing this. Probably this is not good.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    //some data
    int a;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived() {}
    //some extra data not in base
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, Base*> dervivedObjs;

    Derived* derived = new Derived;
    dervivedObjs.emplace(0, derived);

    Derived* derivedPtr = reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(dervivedObjs.at(0));

    return 0;
}
```

How can avoid casting everytime i need to access some data on a derived class?

or is there a most performant way?

Comment: `Derived* derivedPtr = reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(dervivedObjs.at(0));` - ouch, please don't ever do that. If *anything* you want a `dynamic_cast` there, *not* a `reinterpret_cast`. `reinterpret_cast` should almost *never* be used.

Comment: Put the common virtual methods in `Base`; use `dynamic_cast` (and test) when you __have__ to call methods on `Derived` directly.  This assumes that there will be more than 1 class derived from Base.

Comment: If you do `std::map<int, Base*>` it reads: you might store (pointer to) any class object derived from `Base` (not just only `Derived`); then it doesn't make sense to `reinterpret_cast<Derived*>` because you don't know the runtime type of your object...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can avoid casting everytime i need to access some data on a derived class?

By providing an appropriate interface:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    //some data
    int a;
    virtual int get_b() = 0;
};
```

Now `Derived` can override `get_b` to provide access to its member `b`.

**PS**

More precisely `Derived` and all other classes inheriting from `Base` would **have to** provide a definition for `get_b`, because `get_b` is pure virtual.

If some classes deriving from `Base` cannot do that, you could consider to make `get_b` non-abstract in `Base` ... long story short: Don't.

The desire to cast is almost always a sign for wrong design. What you are trying at the moment is to fight your design. Instead of casting you should go one step back and consider if a `std::map<int, Base*>` is what you really want. The sloppy translation of this data structure is: "I want a container whose elements have the interface as defined in `Base`, other than that I do not care about the dynamic type of the objects."

If you ever have to cast a `Base*` to `Derived*` then use [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) has a very limited number of allowed uses and is not meant to be used for casts along a class hierarchy.

**TL;DR**

> How can avoid casting everytime i need to access some data on a derived class?

Just don't do it.

Comment: derived has diferent data.

Comment: (edited because pressed enter accidentally)
Thanks for the answer.
derived has different data.
using this: virtual int get_b() = 0;
i'm forced to override in a derived class that wont have to do that. But i can use it as non pure virtual, but you said don't. why?

And what would be a better design? i'm ok to redeseing because i'm learning.

Comment: @Martin the article I had in mind, I didnt find anymore, anyhow, "don't" because you don't want each class deriving from `Base` carry a `get_b` method that can only return a dummy value, just because one derived class has a `b` member. To propose a better design one would need to know what you want to design for. `Base` and `Derived` dont really tell what those classes are supposed to be good for. Though, SO isnt the place to discuss design I am afraid (there might be other Q&As on SE where this would be ontopic).

Answer (score 0):

Using Base pointer to store pointers to derived classes is useful in the these cases:

1- you have many objects instantiated from different classes that derived from Base and want to store them in one container
2- you want to do common tasks on those objects which should declared as virtual functions in Base class

then you don't need to cast to derived class